# Complex query with query builder in Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have 3 tables,

`subscribers`:

[image]

`subscribers_lists_subscribers`:

[image]

And `subscribers_lists`:

[image]

I am trying to have a query like this:

```
$baseQuery = DB::table('subscribers_lists')
    ->leftjoin('subscribers_lists_subscribers', 'subscribers_lists.id', '=', 'subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscribers_list_id')
    ->leftjoin('subscribers',  'subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscriber_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
    ->select(
        'subscribers_lists.id as count_clickers',
        DB::raw('count(subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscribers_list_id where subscribers.status = "Active") as count_active')
        'subscribers_lists.updated_at as last_activity'
    )
    ->groupBy('subscribers_lists.id');
```

I need to have this:

```
where subscribers.status = "Active"
```

I am getting an error, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you can't have a `where` for only one field. The correct syntax is to put the `where` after the `select` and before `groupBy`.

Comment: So, how can I do it, please help

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You should consider replacing those screenshots with textual equivalents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it,

```
   $baseQuery = DB::table(  'subscribers_lists')
                            ->leftjoin('subscribers_lists_subscribers', 'subscribers_lists.id', '=', 'subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscribers_list_id')
                            ->leftjoin('subscribers',  'subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscriber_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
                            ->select(
                                        'subscribers_lists.id',
                                        'subscribers_lists.name',
                                        'subscribers_lists.id as count_openers',
                                        'subscribers_lists.id as count_clickers',
                                        DB::raw('count(case when subscribers.status = "Active" then 1 else null end) as count_active'),
                                        DB::raw('count(case when subscribers.status = "Unsubsribed" then 1 else null end) as count_unsubsribers'),
                                        DB::raw('count(case when subscribers.status = "Bounced" then 1 else null end) as count_bounced'),
                                        DB::raw('count(subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscribers_list_id) as count_total'),
                                        'subscribers_lists.updated_at as last_activity'
                                    )
                            ->where('subscribers_lists.user_id', '=', $user_ID)
                            ->groupBy('subscribers_lists.id');
    $totalData  =   $baseQuery->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after one of the selects, and you can't simply put something like 'where subscribers.status = "Active"' in a select statement.  Try this:

```
$baseQuery = DB::table( 'subscribers_lists')
    ->leftJoin('subscribers_lists_subscribers', 'subscribers_lists.id', '=', 'subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscribers_list_id')
    ->leftJoin('subscribers',  'subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscriber_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
    ->select(
        'subscribers_lists.id as count_clickers',
        DB::raw('COUNT(subscribers_lists_subscribers.subscribers_list_id) as count_active'),
        'subscribers_lists.updated_at as last_activity'
    )
    ->where('subscribers.status', 'Active')
->groupBy('subscribers_lists.id');
```